# jQuery 'event not defined' error on simulated key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am currently trying to use jQuery to enter a selection from a dropdown into a text box, simulate a click to select it, press return, wait for some processing and then press return again.  It's quite a nasty way of getting what I need but it's the only way I can see at the moment.   Here is the code:

```
$('#fav').change(function() 
{
  $('#contract_input').val($('#fav').val());
  $('#contract_input').trigger('click');
  e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
  e.which = 13;
  $('#contract_input').trigger(e).delay(500).trigger(e);
}
```

The issue I am having is that IE8 is giving an error on the page:

> 'Event' is not defined

The click seems to work, it's just the return that does not.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is the `#contract_input` handler bound?  There are much better ways to do this :)

Comment: it's part of a flexbox (http://flexbox.codeplex.com/) to allow a google suggest style function for selecting contract numbers.  The dropdown is an additional option to allow users to automatically enter favourite contract numbers.  As I'm not too hot on javascript I didn't really want to play around with the flexbox itself.

Comment: Try `e = jQuery.Event("keypress"); e.keyCode = 13; $('#contract_input').trigger(e).delay(500).trigger(e);`, any luck?

Comment: Nope, sadly not.  I do find it very odd that if the page is run locally then the first key press seems to work but if it's on the server it doesn't work at all.  Same browser and same computer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `keydown` instead of `keypress` and in IE you could try setting `e.keyCode` instead of `e.which`.

e.g.

```
e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.keyCode = 13;
$('#contract_input').trigger(e).delay(500).trigger(e);
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit again:
$('#contract_input').keypress(function (e) { do Stuff });
Should be used instead
http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: This is totally wrong. What you are doing is appending a keypress-event-handler to the input-field not triggering a keypress-event.

Comment: Been reading the question a few times now and.. You're right.. I think.